# Как аллоцировать память с помощью своего аллокатора?

Tags: c++, память, new

Как аллоцировать память с помощью своего аллокатора ? Можно ли как то передать свой аллокатор в New?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new - пробовали ?

Comment: Переопределить оператор `new`, например...

Comment: @Harry, если в класс в качестве аргумента передается аллокатор(как например в std::vector), как выделить память с помощью этого аллокатора ?

Comment: Сформулируйте, pls, свой вопрос *точно* и *конкретно*...

Comment: @Harry, возьмем к примеру std::map, если мы создаем std::map<int, string> test, то аллокатор по умолчанию для него std::allocator<std::pair<int, string>. Предположим, с помощью этого аллокатора выделяется память для пар ключ - значение, т.е allocator.alocate(), но каким образом память выделяется для нод, содержащих эти пары? Ведь переданные алокатор имеет тип  std::allocator<std::pair<int, string>.

Comment: @Harry, или под ноды память всегда выделяется стандартным аллокатором?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как аллоцировать память с помощью своего аллокатора?

Вызовом его метода `.allocate()` или `.construct()`.

> если мы создаем `std::map<int, string> test`, то аллокатор по умолчанию для него `std::allocator<std::pair<int, string>`. Предположим, с помощью этого аллокатора выделяется память для пар ключ - значение, т.е `allocator.alocate()`, но каким образом память выделяется для нод, содержащих эти пары? Ведь переданные алокатор имеет тип `std::allocator<std::pair<int, string>`

Тип аллокатора - `std::allocator<std::pair<const int, string>>`, это во-первых.

Предполагаю, что аллокатор этого типа вообще не используется, и заменяется другим аллокатором, тип которого определяется через [`std::allocator_traits<...>::rebind_alloc<...>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits). В rebind скорее всего передается тип ноды, а пары лежат прямо внутри нод, а не аллоцируются отдельно.